# qsort structure array deletes everything

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

So I am having trouble using qsort to sort an array of structures.

I used this link as an example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/73853

When I run the program it gives me blanks for the names that were originally in the structure and zeroes for all the values of `gp`.

```
typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*);

struct record
{
    char player[20];
    int gp;
};
struct record entries[15];

int compare(struct record *, struct record *);


void show ()           
{
    int v;
    qsort((void *)entries, 10, sizeof(struct record), (compfunc)compare);
    struct record *p = entries;
    for(v=0;v<counter;v++, p++)
    {
         printf("%s ..... %d \n", p->player , p->gp);
    }
}

int compare(struct record * p1, struct record * p2)
{
     if( p1->gp < p2->gp)
         return -1;
     else if (p1->gp > p2->gp)
         return 1;
     else
         return 0;
}
```

Edit: Hey everyone thanks so much for all your help but, I have tried everything you guys have said and it still just turns everything value to zero

Comment: this should not compile.

Comment: Apart from (compfunc) to (compfn) its working for me

Answer (score 2):

Your call can be simplified, no need to cast to `void *`:

```
qsort(entries, 10, sizeof entries[0], compare);
```

Note use of `sizeof entries[0]` to avoid pointless repetition of the array type.

There should be no cast of the comparison function either, since it should simply be defined to match the prototype:

```
static int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const struct record *ra = a, *rb = b;

  if( ra->gp < rb->gp)
     return -1;
  if (ra->gp > rb->gp)
     return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

By the way, just to be informational, here's a classic (?) way to tersify the 3-way testing that you sometimes see in places like these:

```
return (ra->gp < rb->gp) ? -1 : (ra->gp > rb->gp);
```

I do not argue *for* this way of expressing it, especially not if you're a beginner, but thought I'd include it since it's relevant and might be instructional to have seen.

Comment: The "classic" way I've seen is `return (ra->gp > rb->gp) - (ra->gp < rb->gp);`

Comment: The "classic" way I've seen is `return (ra->gp - rb->gp)` but I don't know if windows' qsort requires the results of the compare function to be in { -1, 0, 1 }, the linux qsort doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that the microsoft support pages are a real mess and not a good source for learning C, your code is missing an `&` here:

```
...
qsort((void *)entries, 10, sizeof(struct record), (compfunc)compare);
...
```

should be

```
...
qsort((void *)&entries, 10, sizeof(struct record), (compfunc)compare);
...
```

also, I think you meant to write

```
...
qsort((void *)&entries, 15, sizeof(struct record), (compfn)compare);
...
```

Comment: Array names are implicitly converted to pointers when used in an expression.

Comment: @luserdroog I know. I just wanted to stick as close as possible to the code provided by the microsoft support page, and by the OP.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't bothered to look at that page. I wonder why they didn't write `(void *)(struct record *)&entries[0]`: much clearer. :)

Comment: Yea the only reason I even used the microsoft page is because on a smilar question on stackoverflow someone posted that link and said that it was a good example haha

Comment: @user2322610 oh, in that case look at unwind's answer or the manpage of qsort (http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)